# How to post video file in yammer through Power automate or Stream?

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, microsoft-flow, media-streaming, yammer-embed

How to post video file in yammer through Power automate or Stream?

Please help me to post the video file along with text in yammer through Power Automate or Stream embedded.

I have tried with embedded  script but is posting direct link on yammer.